# error while working with fbprophet model using cutoffs

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I am facing an issue while trying to work with fbprophet cross_valisation using cutoffs tying to see the results for the last 7 months.
My data is ranging from 2017-01-01 to 2022-07-01

```
df_cv2 = cross_validation(model=m, cutoffs=cutoffs, horizon='30 days')
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-323-75c1d39c86f3> in <module>
----> 1 df_cv2 = cross_validation(model=m, cutoffs=cutoffs, horizon='30 days')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prophet\diagnostics.py in cross_validation(model, horizon, period, initial, parallel, cutoffs, disable_tqdm)
    197 
    198     else:
--> 199         predicts = [
    200             single_cutoff_forecast(df, model, cutoff, horizon, predict_columns)
    201             for cutoff in (tqdm(cutoffs) if not disable_tqdm else cutoffs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prophet\diagnostics.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    198     else:
    199         predicts = [
--> 200             single_cutoff_forecast(df, model, cutoff, horizon, predict_columns)
    201             for cutoff in (tqdm(cutoffs) if not disable_tqdm else cutoffs)
    202         ]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prophet\diagnostics.py in single_cutoff_forecast(df, model, cutoff, horizon, predict_columns)
    251         for props in m.seasonalities.values()
    252         if props['condition_name'] is not None])
--> 253     yhat = m.predict(df[index_predicted][columns])
    254     # Merge yhat(predicts), y(df, original data) and cutoff
    255 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py in predict(self, df)
   1202         else:
   1203             if df.shape[0] == 0:
-> 1204                 raise ValueError('Dataframe has no rows.')
   1205             df = self.setup_dataframe(df.copy())
   1206 

ValueError: Dataframe has no rows.
```

My dataframe looks like this

```
        y   ds
0      -1.0 2017-01-01
978     2.0 2017-02-01
1582    0.0 2017-03-01
2237    0.0 2017-04-01
2902    0.0 2017-05-01
```

I have created my model and applied the fit
and these are my cutoffs

```
cutoffs = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2022-06-01', freq='1MS')
```

resulting:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01',
               '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01',
               '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01',
               '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
               '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I coped with it efficiently setting `horizon = '31 days'` (i.e., the maximum number that could elapse between two months).

This is due to how `index_predicted` (used here: `yhat = m.predict(df[index_predicted][columns])`), is set: `index_predicted = (df['ds'] > cutoff) & (df['ds'] <= cutoff + horizon)`, where cutoff is one of your cutoffs.

It doesn't work with your arguments because, e.g., cutoff (2021-01-01) + horizon (30 days) = 2021-01-31 and in your `df` there isn't a `ds` that is greater than 2021-01-01 and less than or equal to 2021-01-31.

Comment: Format code as code to make it easier to read